# How to add subdomain in .htaccess and force WWW in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have the following code to force WWW in url

```
rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
rewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I want to add a subdomain max.example and refer to www.example.com/update/max directory
If I do not add any rule, max.example.com will redirect to www.example.com/update/max . If I remove force WWW in url it works. But I still need force WWW in url. How to write the rule?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about "If I do not add any rule, max.example.com will redirect to www.example.com/update/max"? If you remove your rules, why does that subdomain redirect to `www.example.com/update/max`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|max)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```