# how to add www in url in magento

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8.1 and I want to add www in our url.

e.g: now my url is like http://example.com/

I want like http://www.example.com/.

I search on google and got this solution:

```
     rewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
     rewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[referenced by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102786/how-to-add-subdomain-in-htaccess-and-force-www-in-url)

I dont know where to put this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow below steps :

1 ) check in system >> configuration >> Web >> Unsecure and Secure check correct url are setup or not.

2) .htaccess changes :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursitename.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursitename.com$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to add the base url is in the system configuration, NOT rewrite rules in the .htaccess. First of all, make sure you have a CNAME record for www.example.com in your domain's zone file. Second, if you set http://www.example.com/  for your unsecure base url, and https://www.example.com/ for your secure base url, Magento will redirect to those urls during routing. For goodness sake, don't do any Magento redirection in your htaccess.

[image]

You can also set the redirect type code:

[image]

Comment: Magento's redirects ignore the path segment of the URL. So if you go to `http://example.com/some-product`, Magento will redirect you to `http://www.example.com/`, dropping you off on the home page. Furthermore, Magento's redirects are `302` (temporary) redirects, not `301` (permanent) redirects, which is detrimental to SEO. It's best that the non-`www `to `www` redirect is issued at the server level, keeping the URL path intact, and using a `301` redirect instead of a `302`. Of course, as you've mentioned, the URLs should be set up correctly in the configuration as well.

Comment: You can also set the response code in Magento as well as PHP. See above screenshot for Magento. For PHP, see the header function documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php.

Comment: thank you for reply, i did that what you guys suggested, but after that my domain is changed t www but only for home page. when i try to go another page , it redirected to home page or show the error: Not Found

The requested URL /top-sellers/playskool.html was not found on this server.

Comment: please tell me, what to do now?

Comment: Make sure you remove all custom redirects from your htaccess.